# Filter Dataframe in Python for TRUE/FALSE values in a specified column

Tags: python, string, dataframe, filter

I am loading a csv file in Python and then filtering values as indicated below:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

fileloc = "C:/Users/products.csv"
stock_items = pd.read_csv(fileloc)
filtered = stock_items[(stock_items['canAddToCart'] == 'TRUE')]
print(filtered)
```

The canAddToCart column has a TRUE or FALSE value in it. The attempt to filter on it returns an empty Dataframe. I made sure I had the column name case exactly correct. However, if I filter on any other column for example:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

fileloc = "C:/Users/products.csv"
stock_items = pd.read_csv(fileloc)
filtered = stock_items[(stock_items['seller'] == 'Bob')]
print(filtered)
```

That works.
I am puzzled as to why I am able to filter all columns except for the column with the TRUE or FALSE
string in it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that pandas is loading that column as Boolean type (not String).
So what you have to do is :

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

fileloc = "C:/Users/products.csv"
stock_items = pd.read_csv(fileloc)
filtered = stock_items[(stock_items['canAddToCart'] == True)]
print(filtered)
```

That's my guess, due I have not access to yuor data.

Comment: That did it.Thanks!

Comment: So @NeilS please mark my answer as correct and rate it please. thanks